# Click event with react-apexcharts

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I'm using `react-apexcharts` and I want to add an event on a pie chart once users click on one of the sections. Here is my chart:

```
<div className="pie">
    <Chart options={{
        labels: [
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday"
        ],
        theme: {
            monochrome: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 480,
            options: {
                chart: {
                    width: "100%"
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                }
            }
        }]
    }}
    colors={["#1B2260"]}
    series={[44, 55, 41, 17, 15]}
    labels={["Apple", "Mango", "Orange", "Watermelon"]}
    type="pie"
    width="300" />
</div>
```

When users click on the "Apple" section, I want to print "Apple". [This](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/#click) is the best documentation I can find for the click event but I can't get it to work.

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Is this something you are looking for https://codepen.io/junedchhipa/pen/rqQWjW ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding this to your options object:

```
chart: {
    events: {
    dataPointSelection: (event, chartContext, config) => { 
        console.log(config.w.config.labels[config.dataPointIndex])}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[**here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-eywk0) is the working example of your code

You can use `dataPointSelection` event to which is fired when clicked of any datapoint.

As per the doc on apexCharts:

> **dataPointSelection**  Fires when user clicks on a datapoint
>   (bar/column/marker/bubble/donut-slice).  The third argument, in
>   addition to the config object, also includes additional information
>   like which dataPointIndex was selected of which series.  If you have
>   allowMultipleDataPointsSelection enabled, the third argument includes
>   selectedDataPoints property to get all selected dataPoints.

In your case you have to add and new property under options:

```
chart: {
    events: {
    dataPointSelection: (event, chartContext, config) => { 
        // this will print mango, apple etc. when clicked on respective datapoint
        console.log(config.w.config.labels[config.dataPointIndex])}
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, Happy coding